# Что если скрипты и стили запрашивать через require_once?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть около 20 страниц, которые находятся в одной папке.
К каждой из них подключаются одни и те же скрипты и стили, и я подумал "

> а что если их разделить на 2 файла и запрашивать их через `require_once`?
>
> framework'и php не рассматриваю

Это работает, но влияет ли это вообще на подгрузку, и как? И какие негативные последствия с этого?

Comment: о каких скриптах речь?

Comment: *Что вопрос, что ответ.. Не совсем ясно что к чему..*

Comment: js/css в основном пока думал о них.

Comment: Если вы хотите затащить стили и скрипты в отдаваемый HTML, то идея не очень. Сейчас везде используется Keep-Alive, то есть количество скриптов и стилей, подгружаемое с одного хоста, не особо имеет значение. Кроме того, когда веб-сервер автоматически работает с файлами, то он может отдавать заголовок 304 (файл не изменился), либо отдавать файл по частям (partial requests), еще что-то.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, получается разницы нет. Хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно. Создайте единый всегда вызываемый header.php и вызывайте скрипты оттуда. В случае require_once последующие подключения этого скрипта будут просто проигнорированы, никакой дополнительной нагрузки это не создаст, более того, в будущем вы сможете добавить туда autoload для вендора

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Я просто подгружаю на эти страницы: Верхнюю навигацию, нижнюю, и футер, а помимо подумал на счет js/css. Приоритет загрузки то понятен, а вот взаимодействие их друг с другом) Пока, вроде, на стадии разработки проблем нету.